# Deleting specific row from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

im a beginner at php/mysql, its like my first site. What i am trying to do is a loop which shows records from mysql (that works) with delete button so i can delete whole row whenever i want. I wrote the code but it doesnt work.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<table><TR><TD class='nazwa'>" . $row["nazwa"] .
     "</br></TD><TD class='opis'>" . $row["opis"] .
     "</br></TD><TD class='fotka'> <img src=". $row["zdjecie"] .
     "></br></TD><TD class='linkowanko'>" . $row["link"] .
     "</TD></TR>\n</br></br></br></table>";
     //usuwansko
     $row["id"] = $_GET['id'];
      echo "<form action='marta.php' method='post'>
     <INPUT TYPE = 'submit' Name = 'Submit1' VALUE = 'Usun'>
     </form>";
      if (isset($_POST["Submit1"] ) ) 
      {
      mysql_query($db,"DELETE FROM marta WHERE id = $id");
      }
```

PS. I know it might be terrible, sorry for that :/

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, it does nothing
http://chcemyto.cba.pl/marta.php here is the page, u can try for urself

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you'll actually be using this to create a live website, or just doing it for training. But there are a couple of things that stand out immediatly when I look at your code.

By far the worst thing that you're doing here is using user data directly from a form and using it in a mysql query. This is a *huge* security risk. You should sanitize your input at least with `mysql_real_escape_string`. But I'd recommend you'd start using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Second you're querying the database in a loop which is really inefficient. You should collect all the `id`'s first and put them in an array, and then query the database with those id's.

Third, I don't see you place the id in any of the rows. So you don't actually know what the `id` is of the data you're trying to delete.

Fourth; You're creating a table every time instead of creating rows. You should just create a table once and add new rows to it.

Comment: +1 There are actually more problems with this code. It suffers from basic business logic and presentation separation and tightly-couples storage logic

Comment: @bad_boy yeah I could have kept going, but I thought I'd keep it short ;)

Comment: my id is just autoincrement option in database, if i just display the row[id] it shows the right number

Comment: @xox1141 yeah, but you're not using it anywhere in your form ;)